# Como apertar o botão de seguir do Instagram? com python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, instagram-api

Eu estou tentando criar um robo para seguir pessoas no instagram, mas eu empaquei  na parte mais importante, a de clicar em seguir a pessoa. Eu estou usando a linguagem python e o selenium, gnt eu já coloquei de td, por class, xpath, link text, css e ND VAI. E sim, eu estou colocando os codigos certinho sem faltar nenhuma letra ou numero e um tempo de espera de 35s, a página carrega, mas o botão de seguir não é selecionado, sempre aparece o erro NoSuchElementException. ME AJUDEM PF

Já tentei:

```
seguir = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Seguir")
        seguir.click()
```

Já tentei por xpath:

```
seguir = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//button[@class='_5f5mN       jIbKX  _6VtSN     yZn4P   ']")
        seguir.click()
```

Já tentei também por class:

```
seguir = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_5f5mN       jIbKX  _6VtSN     yZn4P   ')
        seguir.click()
```

E várias outras formas e nenhuma vai. O codigo do botão que quero clicar é esse:

```
<span class="vBF20 _1OSdk">
    <button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX  _6VtSN     yZn4P   ">Seguir</button></span>
```

O código completo é esse:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import random

class testebot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="D:\Desktop\driver\geckodriver.exe")
    
    def entrar(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.execute_script("")
        campo_usuario = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
        campo_usuario.click()
        campo_usuario.clear()
        campo_usuario.send_keys(self.username)
        campo_senha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
        campo_senha.click()
        campo_senha.clear()
        campo_senha.send_keys(self.password)
        campo_senha.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(15)
        driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.instagram.com/tiffanymikaely/', '_blank')")
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button').click()

teste = testebot ('username', 'senha').entrar()
```

se ajuda, no html do instagram tem uns flex e event. Sou nova em programação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar XPath ou qualquer outro método de seleção, utilize o seguinte:

```
seguir = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button')
seguir.click()
```

Eu utilizei este código e consegui clicar no botão. E, realmente, utilizando outros métodos não foi possível localizar o botão de seguir. Talvez seja alguma medida de segurança do Instagram para evitar bots, mas com o código acima é possível automatizar essa função.

Comment: ele está achando o botão, mas n clica ;-;

Comment: Então tente fazer assim: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button').click(), sem guardar o botão numa variável, e veja se ele consegue clicar. Qual navegador você está utilizando?

Comment: n foi tbm, firefox

Comment: Teria como você colocar o código completo no post? Oculta senhas e informações confidenciais

Comment: pronto, já postei

Comment: Eu rodei o código aqui e consegui clicar no botão seguir. Eu substituí a linha " driver.execute_script("window.open('url do perfil do instagram', '_blank')")" por driver.get("url do perfil do instagram") e funcionou. Demora um pouco para executar, então ao rodar o programa espere alguns segundos depois do comando para clicar no botão ser executado.

Comment: MUITO OBG, MUITO OBG MSM, MDS OBG JOÃO VICTOR

Comment: você é um anjo, obg

Comment: À disposição =)